# WPF textbox : set cursor position to last character received on property changed handler in View Model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Setup: WPF application utilizing MVVM via Prism

In my application I have a textbox in which I am prompting my user for a Date input. The WPF textbox is bound to my ViewModel inheriting BindableBase (using Prism). When my Date text box is changed I am calling a custom method to apply a Date Mask to the input on my view (MM/DD/YYYY). In my helper method I am also injecting "/" characters to enforce my format.

Problem: If a user repeats the same number 3 times in a row for the first 3 positions then the cursor will jump back to one of the previous inputs (ex. 111). This does not happen if a repetition of 3 occurs anywhere else in the input. This also does not occur if the number is not repetitive (121)

For example: 
user enters November 11 (1111)
As the user is typing the third 1 then the cursor will jump back between the first and second characters in the textbox

[image: Image to help describe issue]

I am stumped on why this is occurring and open to other options on how to handle this. I've looked into trying to bind the CaretIndex for that textbox to a property in my view model but it is not able to be bound so that option is out. Any other ideas or insights on to what I am doing wrong to cause this would be much appreciated.

Any obvious issue with my FormatDate method that would result in this? Is it even possible to set the cursor (caret Index) from a ViewModel?

ViewModel:

```
public class CheckInViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private string _dob;
    public string DOB
    {
        get { return _dob; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _dob, FormatDate(value)); }
    }

    private string FormatDate(string val)
    {
        string clean = new string(new string(val.Where(a => char.IsDigit(a)).ToArray()).Take(8).ToArray());
        char[] chars = { 'M', 'M','/', 'D', 'D','/', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y' };
        int i = 0;
        foreach (char c in clean)
        {
            if (i == 2 || i == 5)
            {
                chars[i] = '/';
                i++;
            }
            chars[i] = c;
            i++;
        }
        return new string(chars);
    }
}
```

View (textbox in question):

```
<TextBox Margin="20,3,5,13" Text="{Binding DOB, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="120" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Birthdate"  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}"/>
```

Comment: This obviously happens because you are formatting (and thus changing) the text while the user is typing. You should use a MaskedTextBox control.

Comment: @Clemens I originally thought this was the case as well but the behavior does not occur when I enter 121 or any other non-repetitive value. It does still occur regardless if I enter 111 in quick or very slow succession.

Comment: This is an internal behavior of the `TextBox`. When you change the text in the `TextBox` after typing, the control tries to restore the caret position to the character that was last typed. And since there are repetitive characters in the text, it chooses the first found character. Try hardcoding `"9876543210"` in the property setter and type `1` - the caret will jump to the position of the `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle SourceUpdated event for your TextBox (don't forget NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True in your binding) an set carret index to the last character in it.

```
<TextBox Margin="20,3,5,13" Text="{Binding DOB, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" MinWidth="120" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Birthdate"  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" SourceUpdated="TextBox_SourceUpdated"/>

        private void TextBox_SourceUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
    {
        var txtBx = sender as TextBox;
        if (txtBx == null || txtBx.Text==null) return;          
        if (txtBx.CaretIndex == 2 || txtBx.CaretIndex == 5)
        {
            txtBx.CaretIndex = txtBx.CaretIndex + 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This won't work because the text length in the OP's case is always 10. So the caret will be always at the last position.

Comment: @dymanoid You are right! I have tested on a simple TextBox an added always one more character to reproduce the issue. Hmm, I have to think.. ;)

Comment: @dymanoid I have changed setting of carret index from last character to specific one.

Comment: Implemented and this resolves the issue. Thank you for your time!